# (Gridview)1st record is being deleted from database c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">           
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add Records">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" OnClick="btnadd_Click" CommandName="insert"
                        Text="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete Records">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" OnClick="btndelete_Click" CommandName="delete"
                        Text="delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("client_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblemail" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Google Email">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblgemail" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("google_email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Number">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcont" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("contact_number") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="role">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblrole" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("role") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have a table with 100 record

This is my Gridview I have two buttons add and delete(on Delete buttonClick particular record should be deleted from database) like, I clicked on record number 35(record number 35 should be deleted) but instead record number 1 is being deleted everytime.

```
public void delete()
{ 

    foreach (GridViewRow g in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Label lblname = (Label)g.FindControl("lblname");
        Button btnde = (Button)g.FindControl("btndelete");
        //Response.Redirect("cs.aspx");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from clientrequest where client_name='" + lblname.Text + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
        con.Close();
    }
}



protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    delete();
    GridView1.Visible = false;

}
```

This is my CS code.

Comment: Read about parameterized queries and sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because on delete you are deleting record using foreach loop which is not a good way to do. You could try out this:

```
public void delete(string Name)
{ 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from clientrequest where client_name='" + Name + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
        con.Close();
}
```

And on Delete button click find the particular row and send it to delete Method

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    string name = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblname")).Text;
    delete(name);
    GridView1.Visible = false;

}
```

Note: Also you could write your redirection inside button click event on basis of delete method return.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your Label control position and get their value, then delete from database. It will work fine.

```
 public void delete()
    { 

foreach (GridViewRow g in GridView1.Rows)
{
  if(g.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{ 
 Label lblname = (Label)g.FindControl("lblname");
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from clientrequest where client_name='" + lblname.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
    con.Close();
    break;
}             
}
}
```